# Web Development ported to iPhone

Tags: iphone

We want to make an iPhone app but we would like to be able to do web development on some sort of framework, and then use something to kind of port this into an iPhone app for us.

Is there anything out there that exists like this?

Comment: I'd suggest Titanium over anything. We're currently creating an Android app using it and it's good. We tried out Phonegap. Check out jQeryMobile for actually developing the app too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out Phonegap.

Please see these questions:

[Comparison between Corona, Phonegap, Titanium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482586/comparison-between-corona-phonegap-titanium)

[How to integrate html5 and iphone applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581944/how-to-integrate-html5-and-iphone-applications)

Some discussion about general webapp verus native app issues:

[iPhone apps: Webapps or native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842230/iphone-apps-webapps-or-native)